# Select browser to view html file stored on SDcard

Tags: android, android-intent

My App creates a form, and saves it as a html file on SD card.
I can load the html file into a webview, so the user can view the form,

However, i would like the user to be able to also view the file in a browser of their choice.
(Ive noticed firefox has 'save as pdf' function, which the user may find useful.)

How can i do this using an intent. I tried but the App closed with an error..

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: post the code that you tried with, and find the stack trace from the exception in the logcat, and post that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will open your html file in the stock browser application:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(uri);
browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

I would imagine that it would work for firefox if you find the packagename / activity name for the firefox application and replace the stock browser ones in the `setClassName()` method. But ultimately it would've been up to Mozilla to implement this functionality, and I've not tested to see if they did or not.